# Avoid StackOverflowError in clojure with reduce

Tags: clojure

The simple code

```
(reduce concat (take 10000 (repeat '(1))))
```

causes a StackOverflowError.  Suppose I have a large list of lists, like the one I obtain in this example with `take`.  How can I merge them in one list as I tried?

Comment: What's wrong with `(take 10000 (repeat 1))`?

Comment: @Bill It was only to show the problem, actually I had to concat different lists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is that `concat` returns a lazy seq (and stacks the function calls until the element's realization). You can fix it by realizing the concatenated collection:

`(reduce (comp doall concat) (take 10000 (repeat '(1))))`

but it is really slow.

in your case i would rather use something like this:

`(reduce into [] (take 10000 (repeat '(1))))`

it would eagerly add all the elements from every collection one by one to the resulting vector.

otherwise (if the `reduce` usage is not for some special extra purpose) you could just do so:

`(apply concat (take 10000 (repeat '(1))))`

which results to a single call of the `concat`, producing a lazy seq

Comment: Thank you, I haven't thought about apply

Answer (score 0):

If `(take 10000 (repeat 1))` won't work because the thing that you want to repeat already comes in a bunch `seq`s or lists, then you might also consider this.

```
(flatten (take 10000 (repeat [1])))
```

It seems to be more clear.